# What could be the source of sediment found in washing machine?

Tags: plumbing, appliances

I had my basement finished and had them put in lines for washing machines.

Now, after the first use or two of the washer, it won't drain.  I looked at the filter, and I found a lot of this stuff: [image: sediment].  There's not much in the picture since I threw most of it out first, but I'd say I've found a few ounces of it at least on multiple occasions after clearing the filter and drain hose of it.

When I I flushed out the drain hose, I didn't really find anything that seemed like it could be the source.

I asked the previous owner of the machines twice, and he said he hadn't had any problems with it.

Could this be coming from the water line?  Or could someone have maybe run the washer with a whole bunch of rocks?!?  I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Have you been getting sediment in any of your other plumbing fixtures?  It isn't uncommon for older iron pipes to "shed" a layer of rust and mineral deposits after they've been drained an recharged.

Comment: Not that I've noticed. The house is 10 years old.

Comment: Is it crumbly? It kind of hard to tell from the picture, but my second guess would be deteriorated rubber from the inside of an old supply line.

Comment: How old is the machine? It seems odd to me that a 10 yr old house would have crud like that in the pipes. Can you ask the plumber where it's coming from?im thinking it's the machine.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it's mostly crumbly and a few solid pieces that seem like very small rocks.

Comment: @Comintern I am pretty sure you are correct.  After running it again and checking the filter immediately when it stopped draining, there was fresh pieces of rubber in the filter.  I replaced the supply hoses with braided steel hoses, and it runs fine now.  It's odd to me that a relatively small amount of sediment/rubber would clog it up and stop it, but changing the hoses did the trick! Thank you!  (If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 1):

Kids. Pockets. Dirt.

Even adults trek in a lot of dirt on their clothes. I would worry about it. That's what the filter is for and now you know how to clean it.

Comment: Okay, but after I cleaned it, the washer stopped draining after 3 cycles.